# Parsing "as this child's parent or guardian"

Tags: meaning, sentence-construction, grammaticality

> Do you provide your consent as this child's parent or guardian for them to have access to website?

This is a sentence appeared on website, but I am confused about the sentence structure, in the *as* clause, they dont have a verb, and dont make clear what is the consent to.

Comment: The main verb is *consent* and the object of the verb is *access to X*. The actual problem with the sentence is that there is no pronoun or article before *website*. It should be "*this* website" (or at least "*the* website").

Answer (score 2):

That is because "as" is not introducing a clause in this case. The meaning is "Do you, as the child's parent or guardian, consent that the child have access to this website."

Formally, it involves an ellipsis: "Do you, [in your legal capacity] as the child's parent or guardian, consent ..."

It is not a well written sentence.

Answer (score 1):

There is no *as* clause; *as* is being used as a preposition here. As [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/as_1) has it, meaning four applies:

> You use *as* when you are indicating what someone or something is or is thought to be, or what function they have.

The sentence you quote could be rewritten as

> Do you, being this child's parent or guardian, provide your consent for the child to have access to the website?

An *as statement* to indicate that someone is being, speaking, acting, etc. in the capacity, role, condition, etc. of something is very common; you may have seen formulations like

> As a taxpayer, I demand to know why this road is still not repaired.

Comment: Thank you so much. Your explanation has already made this clear. I found out finally what's most confused in this sentence is not the usage of as, but the consent for someone to do, as I only knew consent to something. in this case, it is different from that typical usage, as a result, I interpreted it in the way for them follows the guardian not with consent. if it were interpreted in my way, the sentence would become strange and hard to understand.